# emacs in console mode does not work

Tags: emacs

When I launch emacs in console mode or in terminal with -nw option, emacs launches in terminal but none of keys work. I cannot type anything or even cannot exit by C-x C-c. Though I can see a blinking cursor. Same emacs works fine in GUI mode. Any clues will be helpful. I'm running debian 2.6.

Comment: Is `emacs -nw -Q` any different? What about a different terminal emulator?

Comment: What is the exactly command you are running? `emacs -nw &` might cause weirdness like this (it might display, but won't accept any input because it's running in background)

Comment: dbr: Usually the tty also won't allow a background job to write to it, so I think something else would need to be messed up for that to be the case. `stty sane` would normally sort out any usual settings.

Comment: emacs -nw -Q did not work either. I ran into this problem when I started debian without kde desktop and noticed that my emacs(which I started by just using emacs command on terminal) does not work. Later on noticed the same problem with emacs -nw in kde desktop.

Comment: In nut shell, I cannot use emacs  without desktop environment. Command in terminal mode is only "emacs"

Comment: Debian 2.6 doesn't appear to be a real version?? It looks like after 2.2 the next release was 3.0. Are you using the default emacs package? Have you tried updating it? What does `emacs --version` report?

Comment: I have Debian with the kernel version 2.6 and emacs 23.3.1.  `emacs -nw -q -Q` freezes during the startup.  It freezes even with --no-site-file --no-desktop.  `htop` shows this and any instance of `emacs -nw` consuming a 100% of a core all the time.  `strace` shows that emacs has received a SIGSTOP.  `kill -2 4191` causes it to stop again on SIGIO.  I was trying to answer this question and this is what I found so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue by installing emacs23-nox. Probably it installed any missing dependency. Now launching emacs in terminal mode works. Interestingly, when I had uninstalled and installed emacs again, that did not resolve the problem. Anyway, I'm all set.